# How come I get "mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory."

Tags: mysql

Following [this tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/mysql/create-mysql-root-user-account-mysqladmin), I'm getting

> # sudo service mysqld start
>
> Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The mysql daemon in Ubuntu is packaged as `mysql`, not mysql**d**.

```
sudo service mysql start
```

That's really all there is to that one.

Comment: Unless it does not work

Comment: After a reboot it works for me, strange to speak about reboot in Linux, maybe a PATH problem ?

Comment: Just to make things a bit more confusing, sometimes use mysqld sometimes mysql. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

> **WARNING**: This solution will destroy any DB data you have.  DO NOT use it if you have DB data you intend to keep!

I got stuck with the same issue and I uninstalled and installed again by following the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-server mysql-common mysql-client`.
2. `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade && sudo apt autoremove`.
3. `sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client`.

Comment: What about the data existing in current mysql?

Comment: Instead of removing just run this `sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server mysql-client`

Comment: this is actually very dangerous, it will destroy your database.